# Prompt in MySql procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, prompt

Is there a way to prompt a user for a  "yes/no" input, depending on some condition in a MySql procedure?

Comment: You could just delete this question

Answer (score 0):

Not, is not possible to do that.

The procedural language doesn't have interactive with user, you must implement using your used programming language.